# JQuery animation queue executing in reverse order?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I've got a recursing function that's stepping the animation of an element on the page:

```
_this = this;
this.x = 0, this.y = 0;
this.targX = 5, this.targY = 5; 

this.go = function(){
    var xDir = 0, yDir = 0, finished = false;

    if(this.x>this.targX){
        console.log("Reverse x");
        xDir = -1;
    }else if(this.x<this.targX){
        console.log("Forward x");
        xDir = 1;
    }else{
        xDir = 0;
        if(this.y>this.targY){
            console.log("Reverse y");
            yDir = -1;
        }else if(this.y<this.targY){
            console.log("Forward y");
            yDir = 1;
        }else{  finished = true;  }
    }
    this.x+= xDir;
    this.y+= yDir;

    if(finished==false){
        this.$c.animate({
            left: "+="+32*xDir,
            top: "+="+32*yDir
        }, 200, _this.go());
    }
}
```

Hopefully this is clear from the code, but the animation is supposed to step in the x-direction first until `this.x` = `this.targX`, then step in the y-direction until `this.y` = `this.targY`. In this case, the element goes right 5 steps, then down 5 steps.

However, in practice, the animation goes down 5 steps then right 5 steps - as if the animation queue is being reversed. If I remove the `_this.go()` call on success, the element goes right one step and stops - so I know I don't have my axes confused somewhere. The console logging even reports in the correct order:

```
Forward x
Forward x
Forward x
Forward x
Forward x
Forward y
Forward y
Forward y
Forward y
Forward y
```

What's going on here, why is the animation queue executing in reverse? Am I doing something wrong, or is this expected behavior for JQuery?

---

**EDIT:** Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/WdYvB/

Comment: Any chance you could set up a fiddle?

Comment: You are *calling* `_this.go()` and passing its result to `animate()` instead of passing the method itself.

Comment: He's right -- use `_this.go` instead of `_this.go()`

Comment: Wow, blew my mind. This explains a couple of other problems I was having too. Thanks so much! Post as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By writing:

```
this.$c.animate({
    left: "+=" + 32 * xDir,
    top: "+=" + 32 * yDir
}, 200, _this.go());
```

You're actually calling `go()` and passing the value it returns (`undefined` in our case) to `animate()`.

You should pass the function itself instead:

```
this.$c.animate({
    left: "+=" + 32 * xDir,
    top: "+=" + 32 * yDir
}, 200, _this.go);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your callback function is being called when you are assigning the callback.

```
  if(finished==false){
        this.$c.animate({
            left: "+="+32*xDir,
            top: "+="+32*yDir
        }, 200, _this.go());  // should be _this.go 
    }
```

Comment: Excellent answer, spot-on - Frederic just beat you to it =/